# Wordpress - Uncaught TypeError: wp.media is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want my users to be able to upload images to my website. **They don't have to be logged in.**

I have a custom Page template where I would like to perform this. And I have the following chunk of code inside my `functions.php`

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.11.3');
....
---------more codes are here---------
....
else if( in_category( $excluded, get_the_ID() ) || get_page_template_slug() == 'mediaCollector.php') {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_style('media_collector', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mediaCollector.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style_responsive', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-responsive.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', plugins_url() . '/my-plugin/css/font-awesome.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('mediaCollectorScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mediaCollector.js');
}
....
---------more codes are here---------
....
```

This is the code for what happens when the Upload image button is clicked (which opens the popup where user can upload media).

```
    \$j = jQuery.noConflict();

    /* Logo Upload */
    \$j(document).ready(function() {
        \$j('.upload-btn').click(function(a) {
            var that = this;
        a.preventDefault();
        var b = wp.media({
            title: 'Upload Image',
            multiple: !1
        }).open().on('select', function(a) {
            var c = b.state().get('selection').first();
            var d = c.toJSON().url;
            \$j(that).parent().find('input[type=text]').val(d)
        });
    });
```

But I am getting the following error on clicking the Upload button.

`Uncaught TypeError: wp.media is not a function`

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

Try adding this

```php
function load_media_files() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_media_files' );
```

also if you get `the reference is missing` in your javascript file, try this as well

```php
wp_enqueue_script('mediaCollectorScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mediaCollector.js', array('jquery', 'media-upload'), '0.0.2', true);
```

Basically you have to add the third argument of `wp_enqueue_script` function which is the dependencies for your javascript, which in this case, would be `jquery` and `media-upload`.

Answer (score 6):

That solution has worked perfectly in my case

Add it in your `functions.php` file of your active theme or in your plugin file.

```php
function load_media_files() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_media_files' );
```